# React hooks & RTK pattern for a series of chained http requests

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rtk-query

In my component, I need to fetch `contestDetails`, get a value from the response (`draftgroupId`), and then fetch the `draftGroup`. Normally I'd wrap them each in `useEffect`:

```js
  const [draftGroupId, setDraftGroupId] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    api.getContestDetails(contestId).then(res => setDraftGroupId(res.draftGroupId));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.getDraftGroupId(draftGroupId).then(res => /* use the response */);
  }, [draftGroupId]);
```

However, I'm making my fetches with RTK Query, so fetches themselves are performed with hooks. RTK Query handles when to fetch and when not to (or something like that), so the first query, `useGetContestByIdQuery(contestId);` can just be at the top level of the component.

The second query, `useGetDraftGroupByIdQuery(draftGroupId);`, however, needs to wait until we have a `contestId`. But you can't call a hook conditionally, so I can't wrap it in an `if`, and you also can't call a hook from another hook, so I can't wrap it in a `useEffect` that would have `contestId` as a dependency like the above example.

I'm not sure if this changes things, but I'm also not using the return value of the RTKQ hooks because I'm handling that data in my own RTK reducers (with `extraReducers`). I don't think that makes a difference, since whether I get `draftgroupId` from redux or whether I get it from the `data` return of the query hook, my problem is still the same.

Here is what I came up with, which is simply wrapping each fetch in its own component, since the components will render conditionally.

```js
const GetContest = ({ contestId, ...props }) => {
  useGetContestByIdQuery(contestId); // populates state.currentDraft for next line
  
  const { draftgroupId, gameTypeId } = useSelector(getCurrentDraftState).contest;

  return !draftgroupId ? null : (
    <GetDraftGroup
      draftGroupId={draftgroupId}
      gameTypeId={gameTypeId}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

const GetDraftGroup = ({ draftGroupId, gameTypeId, ...props }) => {
  useGetDraftGroupByIdQuery(draftGroupId, gameTypeId); // populates state.currentDraft.players for next line

  const players = useSelector(getAllPlayers);

  return !players ? null : <ActualGameScreen {...props} />;
};
```

This cannot possibly be the right way to do this, right? What is the right way to do this with RTK Query?

Comment: Why use RTK Query when there is react-query ?

Comment: @entropyfeverone both tools are similar in featureset and amount of code to write, but differ a bit in mindset. RTK Query might just be the better match to OPs mindset. Also, RTK Query is closer to Redux, so they might need to integrate with a Redux store, which would be a benefit. 
Either way, you could also be asking "why use React Query when there is SWR", "why use SWR when there is react-async", "why use React-Async when there is axios" etc. It's neither constructive nor does it lead anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `skip` option or `skipToken` for your "conditional" case:

```js
useGetContestByIdQuery(contestId ?? skipToken);
```

or

```js
useGetContestByIdQuery(contestId, { skip: !contestId });
```